# click on a dynamically added row and get the index of the cell in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var button = document.getElementById('btn'),
    table = document.getElementById('tableBody');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var row = table.insertRow();
    for (var c = 0; c < 4; c += 1) {
        row.insertCell(c).innerHTML = "cell";
    }
});
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>
        <button id="btn">Insert</button>
      </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableBody">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

How can i click on the dynamically added rows and get the index of the cell i clicked at using either plain JS or jQuery

Comment: In your JS you could give the cells a `data-` attribute when you create them and populate it with the string of the index. e.g `data-index="Column 2 Cell 1"` then have an onclick event for all cells that displays that attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this if you didn't want to mark the cell, (say, if you were going to also delete them in any order) would be to get the click target element, find it's parentNode then check each cell to see if it is the target that you clicked on. So you would say:

define a function like this:

```
function getCellIndexFromClick(event) {
  var i, cell = event.target, nodes = cell.parentNode.childNodes;

  for (i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
    if (nodes[i] === cell) {
      return i; //or do something else with i, or whatever.
    }
  }
}
```

then in your code add:

```
cell.addEventListener("click", getCellIndexFromClick);
```

disclaimer: I haven't actually tried that, I just typed it straight in here.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var button = document.getElementById('btn'),
    table = document.getElementById('tableBody');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var row = table.insertRow();
    for (var c = 0; c < 4; c += 1) {
        row.insertCell(c).innerHTML = "cell";
    }
});

$("body").on("click", "td", function(){
   var column_num = parseInt( $(this).index() ) + 1;
   var row_num = parseInt( $(this).parent().index() )+1;    
   alert( "Row_num =" + row_num + "  ,  Rolumn_num ="+ column_num );   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>
        <button id="btn">Insert</button>
      </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableBody">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```